# Regular expression in First position uppercase letter followed by 5 numbers maximum

Tags: asp.net, regex, numbers, uppercase

I want to make a regular expression that checks an uppercase letter in the first position followed by 5 numbers maximum

Comment: Forgot to ask this, but what language are you using?

Comment: My answer should be fine, then.

Comment: @nhahtdh working well, thanks )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This regex should work:

```
^[A-Z]\d{0,5}$
```

This assert uppercase letter, followed by 0 to 5 digit characters.